# Dual / Bidireactional data binding in Objective-C using `TJBinder `

Tags: objective-c, data-binding, 2-way-object-databinding

With help of nicely written [TJBinder](https://github.com/Neosperience/TJBinder) I am able to hook a view into DTO or model class.

As per example,

```
    // Retrieve your data object from an external resource here
    Fruit* fruit = [Fruit new];
    fruit.name = @"apple";
    fruit.color = [UIColor redColor];

    // Tell the root view what is its data object
    self.view.dataObject = fruit;
```

But now, when there is an UI update say `UITextField` got updated, then how can I bind that into model class ?

So far I tried,

```
    //Now say user typed "orange" instead of "apple" in a text field.
    //After a button action
    fruit = self.view.dataObject;
    NSLog(@"%@", fruit.name); //-> returns old object itself. DTO not updated after changing view.
```

Any help greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently [TJBinder](https://github.com/Neosperience/TJBinder) has `updateView` to communicate

*Model — to— > View*

To achieve

*View  — to— > Model*

I have added additional method `updateModel` in "TJBinder.h"

This method will loop over every `TJBindEntry` object and will set model object value taken from the key path of view.

```
-(void)updateModel{
    
    for (TJBindEntry* entry in self.bindings)
    {
        [self updateBindingEntryForView:entry];
    }
}

-(void) updateBindingEntryForView:(TJBindEntry*)entry
{
 
    id extractedValue = [entry.view valueForKey:entry.viewKey];
    
    [self.dataObject setValue:extractedValue forKey:entry.dataObjectKeyPath];
}
```

[Refer here is complete code in my Gist](https://gist.github.com/jeevanRao7/11fe90cb0a27c2b94225ec3539bdfe7a)